# VIM padding with appropriate number of ",0" to get CSV file

Tags: regex, csv, search, vim, substitution

I have a file containing numbers like

```
 1, 2, 3
 4, 5
 6, 7, 8, 9,10,11
12,13,14,15,16
...
```

I want to create a CSV file by padding each line such that there are 6 values separated by 5 commas, so I need to add to each line an appropriate number of ",0". It shall look like

```
 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0
 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0
 6, 7, 8, 9,10,11
12,13,14,15,16, 0
...
```

How would I do this with VIM?

Can I count the number of "," in a line with regular expressions and add the correct number of ",0" to each line with the substitute `s` command?

Comment: It is possible to use regex and find the number of commas and then use a expr part in replacement part, something like /\=expr(). But there are several ways easier than regex like macros or commands. Take advantage of vim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add six zeros in all lines first, irrespective of how many numbers they have and then, you can delete everything from sixth comma till end in every line.

To insert them,

```
        :1,$ normal! i,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

To delete from sixth comma till end,

```
        :1,$normal! ^6f,D

      ^ moves to first character in line(which is obviously a number here)

       6f,  finds comma six times

        D delete from cursor to end of line
```

Example:

Original

```
             1,2,
             3,6,7,0,0,0
             4,5,6
            11,12,13
```

After adding six zeroes,

```
             1,2,0,0,0,0,0,0
             3,6,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
             4,5,6,0,0,0,0,0,0
            11,12,13,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

After removing from six comma to end of line

```
             1,2,0,0,0,0,0
             3,6,7,0,0,0,0
             4,5,6,0,0,0,0
            11,12,13,0,0,0
```

Comment: You can use selected line numbers or marks instead of `1,$`. This will be a simpler approach than using complex regex.

Comment: As a shot form of `normal`, you can use `norm`

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve that by typing this command:

```
:g/^/ s/^.*$/&,0,0,0,0,0,0/ | normal! 6f,D
```

Answer (score 2):

With `perl`:

```
perl -lpe '$_ .= ",0" x (5 - tr/,//)' file.txt
```

With `awk`:

```
awk -v FS=, -v OFS=, '{ for(i = NF+1; i <= 6; i++) $i = 0 } 1' file.txt
```

With `sed`:

```
sed ':b /^\([^,]*,\)\{5\}/ b; { s/$/,0/; b b }' file.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as how to do this *from inside Vim*, you can also pipe text through external programs and it will replace the input with the output.  That's an easy way to leverage sorting, deduping, grep-based filtering, etc, or some of Sato's suggestions.  So, if you have a script called standardize_commas.py, try selecting your block with visual line mode (shift+v then select), and then typing something like `:! python /tmp/standardize_commas.py`.  It should prepend a little bit to that string indicating that the command will run on the currently selected lines.

FYI, this was my /tmp/standardize_commas.py script:

```
import sys

max_width = 0
rows = []
for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.strip()
    existing_vals = line.split(",")
    rows.append(existing_vals)
    max_width = max(max_width, len(existing_vals))

for row in rows:
    zeros_needed = max_width - len(row)
    full_values = row + ["0"] * zeros_needed
    print ",".join(full_values)
```